# Adding the using clause to the project - beginner

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I created a C# MVC project, and later added a Unit test project to it. The structure now is as follows;

> Solution
>
> |
>
> |_ UnitTest Project
>
> |
>
> |_ MyProject

Now from the unit test project i need to refer the MyProject how can i write it;

I wrote the following but it didn't work;

```
using MyProject.View;
```

How can i solve this ?

Comment: Why not simply `using MyProject;`?

Comment: This rather depends on namespaces more than projects. You add references to assemblies but "use" namespaces. The fact that these broadly aline is a convention bourne of common sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right click "References" within "UnitTest Project" and click "Add Reference...", select your other project from within this dialog.

Comment: Thanks it worked. however i will have to accept your answer after 12 mins.